# Find object in array ids

Tags: javascript

I've list of id's in array and list of article in other array.

I would like filter my `article` array by `ids` find in id's array.

Exemple :

```
const ids = [ '1', '2', '3' ];
const articles = [
  { id: '1', title: 'blua' },
  { id: '10', title: 'blua' }
  ...
];
```

I've try this :

```
ids.map((id) => {
  return audits.find((audit) => {
    return id === audit.id;
  });
});
```

But return underfined :/

I think it's not a good methode ^^

Anyone can help me ?

Thank you !

Comment: Cause theres no `audits` array?!

Answer (score 6):

Use `array.prototype.filter` and `array.prototype.includes`:

```js
const ids = [ '1', '2', '3' ];
const articles = [ { id: '1', title: 'blua' },{ id: '10', title: 'blua' } ];

const filtered = articles.filter(a => ids.includes(a.id));

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Maybe even better using a Set: `ids = new Set(ids); filtered = articles.filter(({id}) => ids.has(id))`

Answer (score 0):

```
const ids = [ '1', '2', '3' ];
const articles = [
  { id: '1', title: 'blua' },
  { id: '10', title: 'blua' }
  ...
];

let results = articles.filter( (a) => ids.indexOf(a.id) !== -1);
```

Comment: adding code only to answers make them pop up as a spam or low-quality post, although you have provided the solution try adding some description to what is happening.